# JQuery IIFE outside document ready - bad pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, module

Hey guys It's been a while that I'm dealing with this kind of "pattern", but I can't appreciate this architectural choice. It seems to me awful and no-sense code.

I attach you a code example to be more explicative.

**Are all of those IIFEs declared outside the document ready a bad practice? Is this a pattern or it is just Spaghetti JS? Any weak points or architectural mistakes?**

Index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV='content-type' CONTENT='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="first"></div>
        <div id="second" style="border:2px solid green;width:150px;height:190px;"></div>

    </body>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/scope.js'></script>


</html>
```

scope.js

```
(function() {
    if (typeof $M === 'undefined') { $M = {}; }


    var 
        $document = $(document);
        $first = $('#first'),
        $second = $('#second'),
        $chunk = $("<div id='chunk'> truffle shuffle </div>"),
        documentHeight = $document.height(),
        animationTime = 1000,
        style = {
            'border':'2px solid red',
            'height': documentHeight / 8,
            'width': '150px'
        },
        style2 = {
            'height': documentHeight / 4,
            'width': '300px'
        };


    var init = function() {

        $second.hide(); // init ops
    }

    function appendChunk() {
        $first.append($chunk);
        $chunk.css(style);
    }

    function animateChunk() {
        $chunk.animate(style2,animationTime,function(){
            $(this).trigger('animationComplete');
        });
    }

    appendChunk();
    animateChunk();

    $M.one = init;
})();


(function() {
    if (typeof $M === 'undefined') { $M = {}; }

    var 
        $second = $('#second'),
        $chunk = $("#chunk"),
        animationTime = 1000,
        style = {
            'border':'2px solid red',
            'height': '150px',
            'width': '150px'
        };

    var init = function() {

        $second.hide(); // init ops
    }

    $chunk.on('animationComplete',function(){
        $second.fadeIn().trigger('animationComplete');
    });

    $second.on('animationComplete',function(){
        $chunk.animate(style,animationTime);
    });

    var time = setInterval(function() {
            if($second.is(':visible')) {
                console.log("visible");
                clearInterval(time);
            } else {
                $second.html("finished!");
            }
    },200);

    $M.two = init;
})();


$(document).ready(function () {

    $M.one();
    $M.two();

});
```

Comment: `I attach you a code example to be more explicative.`  Go on then ;)

Comment: I consider it ridiculous that people who write JS with jQuery feel that you can ONLY have code that's written inside $(document).ready - what if you have code that doesn't need to the DOM to be loaded to execute? What if all your scripts are loaded at the end of your page and are therefore always executed after the DOM is ready?

Comment: Sorry I hit enter before completing the post :-P

Comment: @Adam that's the point. Here all the functions and the modules are conceived to be used only at the document.ready.

Comment: @Adam: FWIW, not all of us do. :-)

Comment: @Mahoney - but the script tags are placed at the end of the document. When the script tags are parsed and their sources downloaded, then the entire document before them has to be ready by definition, otherwise the parser wouldn't have gotten to them.

Answer (score 2):

<s>*Note: As of this writing, there is no code in your question.*</s> It's there now, see below.

> Are all of those IIFEs declared outside the document ready a bad practice?

Not at all, they're useful for scoping.

I normally don't use jQuery's `ready` because I prefer just putting the `script` element at the bottom of the page, so I use an IIFE to avoid having any globals and to be `noConflict`-compatible:

```
(function($) {
    // My code here
}(jQuery);
```

---

*(Now that there's code in the question...)*

But if you're worried about bad practices, you should flag this up:

```
if (typeof $M === 'undefined') { $M = {}; }
```

That relies on [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) and, separately, isn't compatible with ES5's "strict" mode.

Here's a pattern you can use for that situation:

```
// By default, global scope is not strict
(function(global) {
    // Now we turn on strict
    "use strict";

    if (typeof global.$M === 'undefined') { global.$M = {}; }
    var $M = global.$M;

    // ...

})(this);
```

Or on browsers, just use `window`:

```
(function() {
    // Now we turn on strict
    "use strict";

    if (typeof window.$M === 'undefined') { window.$M = {}; }
    var $M = window.$M;

    // ...

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Most people (or at least me!) make use of IIFEs for the following reasons:

### Wrap variables inside a function, so they don't get global

That's much useful. You would be polluting your browser environment with useless variables to other files - so you wrap all the code inside an IIFE and they don't go global, while being accessible to all code inside the function scope. Basically, it's a way of getting "private vars" in JS.

### Reduce minification size by cutting some globals

For example, when you do the following:

```
(function( window, document, undefined ) {
  // ...
})( window, document );
```

Considering that you do use a lot those 3 variables inside that scope, your final, minified file will be *much* smaller:

```
(function( a, b, c ) {
  // code with all references to window, document and undefined renamed
})( window, document );
```

---

I hope this helps you understand why of using IIFEs.
Also, it's always good to read [what Ben Almann's have to say about them](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). He's the creator of [Grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com) :)